# How to modify the CSS Properties (height width) of a div element via JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

How come this doesn't create a vertical 5px-wide bar on the ride side of the window?

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#scrollBar").css({
                height: $(window).height,
                width: 5,
                position: "absolute",                
                top: 0,
                left: $(window).width - 5,
                margin: 0
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scrollBar" style="background-color: Red">test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

I found several problems:

- instead of `$(window).height`, use `$(window).height()`
- instead of `left: $(window).width - 5`, use `right: 0`

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#scrollBar").css({
          height: $(window).height(),
          width: 5,
          position: "absolute",                
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          margin: 0
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: The only problem with 'right' is that IE often mucks it up and is 1px off.

Comment: Would padding/margin help? I don't have IE right now so I can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that jQuery's .width and .height should be .width() and .height().

[Examples of use...](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/width)

Answer (score 1):

you might want to put "5px" instead of 5 for the width and  $(window).height() + "px" for the height and ($(window).width() - 5) + "px" for the left.

Answer (score 1):

From reading jQuery documentation you can see that you need to put the css properties and their values as string values.

```
 $("#scrollBar").css({
                'height': $(window).height(),
                'width': '5px',
                'position': 'absolute',                
                'top': '0',
                'left': $(window).width() - 5,
                'margin': '0'
            });
```

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#properties

I'm not really sure tough how you would display those calculated values.

PS: Jonathas was right height and width are functions, not properties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `left: $(window).width - 5`, you could try `right: 0`.

EDIT: Yeah, that was pretty stupid. But, if I'm not mistaken, those should also be quoted, as in 'width': '5px',.

```
  $("#scrollBar").css({
    'height': $(window).height(),
    'width': '5px',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': 0,
    'right': 0,
    'margin': 0
  });
```